# Sending a ViewModel Instance To another ViewModel Constructor

Tags: c#

```
var sharedViewModel=new SharedViewModel;

var viewModel1 = new ViewModel1(ref sharedViewModel)
var viewModel2 = new ViewModel2(ref sharedViewModel)
var viewModel3 = new ViewModel3(ref sharedViewModel)
```

will there be a difference if i do

```
var viewModel1 = new ViewModel1(sharedViewModel)
var viewModel2 = new ViewModel2(sharedViewModel)
var viewModel3 = new ViewModel3(sharedViewModel)
```

`ViewModel1,ViewModel2,ViewModel3` will be doing changes to the `SharedViewModel` instance, is there a difference between `ref SharedViewModel` and `SharedViewModel` in this case?

Edit:
Example of what will be inside my ViewModel1,ViewModel2,ViewModel3 classes

```
private SharedViewModel sharedvm;

Public ViewModel(SharedViewModel sharedViewModel)
 {
sharedvm=sharedViewModel;
sharedvm.Collection.Add(new object());
 }

private doSomthing()
 {
sharedvm.Collection.RemoveAt(0);
 }
```

now the question is if i add an object to my `sharedvm` collection, does that mean that i am adding an object to my `sharedViewModel` collection?

what about if i call the doSomthing method, will the changes reflect on my sharedViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah there is a difference. 
The value of `SharedViewModel` can be different because you are passing *a reference to a reference* (essentially the `sharedViewModel` variable itself) to the the ViewModel1 constructor.

So if `SharedViewModel` is changed in the ctor, then it will affect the variable in the calling scope. 
By changed I mean in the `ViewModel1` ctor you do this:

```
sharedViewModel = new SharedViewModel()
```

Perhaps, I wasn't clear enough.

If you've done C/C++ think of it this way.

```
object *a = new object()
object **b = &a
func(b)
```

But you still have a high level view because everything is done by the compiler.

**EDIT:
First case**

```
public ViewModel(SharedViewModel sharedViewModel)
{

    sharedvm=sharedViewModel;
    sharedvm.Collection.Add(new object());

}
```

**versus  second case**

```
public ViewModel(ref SharedViewModel sharedViewModel)
{
  sharedvm=sharedViewModel;
  sharedvm.Collection.Add(new object());
}
```

In this scenario, there is absolutely no difference. The same collection in the heap is being modified. So what happens to the collection can be seen by the calling scope.

The difference occurs when in the *first case* you do this:

```
sharedViewModel = new SharedViewModel()
```

Now you are modifying a *completely different object* in memory, and the changes applied to that object's collection is not seen by the calling scope because the calling scope references a *completely different object*.
So usually you never `new` the argument you just passed in. But if for some reason you do `new` the argument, then the `ref` keyword is a way to circumvent the said problem.

Comment: If you want to affect the variable in the calling scope, then there is a difference. And yeah I know it is tagged C#

Comment: @RohitVats I just tested it, and I was right.  Thanks for the dvote

Comment: @user1492051 I've updated my answer. I sure hope it makes sense to you lol

Comment: @LewsTherin it sure does Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, because instance of SharedViewModel is a reference type sa already passed by as reference.
For me you should't use ref in this case.

Ref could be usefull if you want to pass non-reference type (eg. primitive types as int) as reference, so as a pointer.

As you could read on [msdn, about ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

> Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a reference type. There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are already passed by reference. You don't need `ref` keyword at all.